# Ho to fix xpath for lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Can somebody explain me why xptah on elementree works while it fails on element.

1. It's working

   import lxml.etree as et

   xml1 = et.parse(DATA1)

   xml1.xpath("ws:Book[ws:Additional_Information/ws:Book_on_AV='1' or "
   "ws:Chapter2/ws:Has_International_Assignment='false']/ws:Chapter3/ws:Book_Type
   /text()", namespaces=NAMESPACE1)

--Output--
['Regular', 'Regular']

2. It's not working

xp = "[ws:Additional_Information/ws:Book_on_AV='1' or
ws:Chapter2/ws:Has_International_Assignment='false']/ws:Chapter3/ws:Book_Type/text()"

```
for book in xml1.findall("ws:Book", namespaces=NAMESPACE1):
    print(book.xpath(xp, namespaces=NAMESPACE1))
```

ERROR:

```
print(book.xpath(xp, namespaces=NAMESPACE1))
File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1597, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ws:Books xmlns:ws="urn:com.aa/bb" >
    <ws:Book>enter code here
        <ws:Chapter1>
            <ws:Data>
                <ws:Type>Preferred</ws:Type>
                <ws:Book_Name>Book1</ws:Book_Name>
            </ws:Data>
        </ws:Chapter1>
        <ws:Chapter2>
            <ws:Has_International_Assignment>true</ws:Has_International_Assignment>
        </ws:Chapter2>
        <ws:Chapter3>
            <ws:Operation>ADD</ws:Operation>
            <ws:Book_Type ws:PriorValue="">Regular</ws:Book_Type>
        </ws:Chapter3>
        <ws:Additional_Information>
            <ws:Book_on_AV>1</ws:Book_on_AV>
        </ws:Additional_Information>
    </ws:Book>
    <ws:Book>
        <ws:Chapter1>
            <ws:Data>
                <ws:Type>Preferred</ws:Type>
                <ws:Book_Name>Book2</ws:Book_Name>
            </ws:Data>
        </ws:Chapter1>
        <ws:Chapter2>
            <ws:Has_International_Assignment>true</ws:Has_International_Assignment>
        </ws:Chapter2>
        <ws:Chapter3>
            <ws:Operation>ADD</ws:Operation>
            <ws:Book_Type ws:PriorValue="">Regular</ws:Book_Type>
        </ws:Chapter3>
        <ws:Additional_Information>
            <ws:Book_on_AV>1</ws:Book_on_AV>
        </ws:Additional_Information>
    </ws:Book>
</ws:Books>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a path expression with a predicate in square brackets, i.e. your inner XPath expression starting with `[` doesn't work. I would hope that using `.[` instead works (but I haven't tested with lxml/XPath 1.0). If the `.[` gives an error, try `self::ws:Book[`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. The second option worked.